# Do we have undo option in high charts?

Tags: highcharts

Do we have undo option in high charts? For example I have few series on chart and I replaced them with new one. Do I have any option to revert it back?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but 'undo' in the meaning of a special option is not available from the API.

However, there are many options which can be used for removing old and adding new data. In your example, you can use the `remove()` and `addSeries()` methods to achieve that.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tyvbk62s/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#remove
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

You can also consider using `localStorage` as a place for storing `chart.options`.

**Example demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9b3cx178/